# In regression, how to handle categorical independent variable which have category with small size?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, feature-selection

I was trying to fit the linear regression models, which dependent variable is continuous quantitative and independent variables are mixed type of both numeric and categorical.

Before fitting the model, I check the independent variables(especially categorical).

There were several variables which have category with small sample size. For example, variable `X1` have three categories and each category's sample size is 5, 200, and 800. What I was trying to do was, just ignore this kind of variables, but I'm not sure about it make sense or not.

Comment: Careful with just ignoring data! You might look into regularization

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks a lot. I'll take a look at paper about it!!

Comment: @Park Regularization is so common now that you don’t have to go to primary literature for your first exposure to it. I wouldn’t even be surprised if the software documentation (e.g., sklearn) gave a decent first explanation.

Comment: @Dave I was not familiar with that word but I see many information not in papers. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Which word, sklearn? It’s a popular Python package for machine learning.

Comment: @Dave Yes, it's document provides many helpful information!

Comment: You definitely cannot used scarcely populated categories. You can drop or pool them, but this has to be a theoretically informed choice. If this is not the case, another solution could be to argue why this is reasonable given your specific data/sample.